# How to declare multiple times CallbackEventHandler in a class?

Tags: c#

so I got in a c# project in a class:

```
public delegate void CallbackEventHandler(AuthenticateResponse response);
public event CallbackEventHandler Callback;
public event CallbackEventHandler ErrorCallback;
private AuthenticateResponse response;
```

And when I use it I do:

```
        MySingleton.Instance.Callback += delegate (AuthenticateResponse request)
    {
        Debug.Log("Callback=" + request.Response);
    };
    MySingleton.Instance.ErrorCallback += delegate (AuthenticateResponse request)
    {
        Debug.Log("ErrorCallback=" + request.Response);
    };
```

So know in my class where I declare the CallbackEventHandle I want to declare a 2nd CallbackEventHandler, but with different parameters, something like:

```
public delegate void CallbackEventHandler(OtherResponse response);
public event CallbackEventHandler Callback2;
public event CallbackEventHandler ErrorCallback2;
private OtherResponse response2;
```

But when I compile, I get that my class already contains a CallbackEventHandle, is it possible to declare a 2nd CallbackEventHandle in a class that already has an CallbackEventHandle? If possible how do I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028283/can-i-define-2-delegates-with-the-same-name-but-different-parameters

Comment: This post answer my question, since I´m a Java guy I have not realized that CallbackEventHandler was the name of my delegate.

Comment: Note that you can use generic delegates. Then your event will be like CallbackEventHandler<AuthenticateResponse>. Or just use existing Action delegate.